# Trying to apply a function to a large data set by cuting it in small parts in R

Tags: r, large-data

I have a large dataset I am reading in R
I want to apply the `Unique()` function on it so I can work with it better, but when I try to do so, I get this prompted:

```
clients <- unique(clients)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 27.9 Mb
```

So I am trying to apply this function part by part by doing this:

```
clientsmd<-data.frame()
n<-7316738  #Amount of observations in the dataset
t<-0
for(i in 1:200){
  clientsm<-clients[1+(t*round((n/200))):(t+1)*round((n/200)),]
  clientsm<-unique(clientsm)
  clientsmd<-rbind(clientsm)
  t<-(t+1) }
```

But I get this:

```
 Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : subscript too large for 32-bit R
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875795/best-practices-for-storing-and-using-data-frames-too-large-for-memory

Comment: Also: [R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)

Comment: How can I use one of this packages to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: For example I do this:ok<-as.ffdf(clients)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 27.9 Mb | and for the package "bigmemory" it changues my char variables to numbers